# Gremlin - Is there a way for case-insensitive sensitive search?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, tinkerpop

I'm using Gremlin for Cosmos DB. I have vertices labeled 'Person'. In the front-end, I have a search box where the user can enter the name. Even though the user enters a partial name, irrespective of case, I need to get the relevant results by querying the 'Person'.

I found textContains, startingWith but looks like its not supported in the cosmos DB query portal.

Any other alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

> Even though the user enters a partial name, irrespective of case, I
>   need to get the relevant results by querying the 'Person'.

Based on your description, maybe you could use `CONTAINS` operator in your sql.

```
SELECT c.label,c.name FROM c where CONTAINS(c.label, 'Per')
```

Output:

[image]

---

Update Answer:

Based on my searching for the [list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/gremlin-support#gremlin-steps) supported by Cosmos DB Gremlin API, `startswith` or `contains` can't be touched so far.

You could refer to this [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v2/issues/473) which is mentioned in this [thread](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v2/issues/413).Or you could submit feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db?category_id=321991) to push the progress about the features.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Jay. I need the query in Gremlin. Any idea on that?

Comment: @user1472423 Please refer to the update answer,thanks.

Comment: @user1472423 Hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: Apologies for this, Jay. Yeah, your answer helped, but pity that Cosmos DB missing such a basic feature. What's your say on this?